# Reading the first record from array of Json records in a json file in JAVA

Tags: java, json

How to get the first record from a JSON File that contains array of JSON Records

Sample File:

```
[
{"l7ProtocolID":"dhcp","packets_out":1,"bytes_out":400,"start_time":1454281199898,"flow_sample":0,"duration":102,"path":["base","ip","udp","dhcp"],"bytes_in":1200,"l4":[{"client":"68","server":"67","level":0}],"l2":[{"client":"52:54:00:50:04:B2","server":"FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF","level":0}],"l3":[{"client":"::ffff:0.0.0.0","server":"::ffff:255.255.255.255","level":0}],"flow_id":"81454281200000731489","applicationID":"dhcp","packets_in":1}
{"l7ProtocolID":"dhcp","packets_out":1,"bytes_out":400,"start_time":1454281199898,"flow_sample":0,"duration":102,"path":["base","ip","udp","dhcp"],"bytes_in":1200,"l4":[{"client":"68","server":"67","level":0}],"l2":[{"client":"52:54:00:50:04:B2","server":"FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF","level":0}],"l3":[{"client":"::ffff:0.0.0.0","server":"::ffff:255.255.255.255","level":0}],"flow_id":"81454281200000731489","applicationID":"dhcp","packets_in":1}
Record n.....
]
```

And simillarly there might be 1000+ records in the file.

I want to fetch the first record out of this file.

Comment: Please read [ask]. There are a million different ways to answer this, and although you've got an answer you shouldn't have. You'll do better in future by showing us what you have done to solve the problem, and asking specific questions about the bits you're stuck on. We're not here to write your code for you, which is what you're asking.

Comment: got it Solved , added answer. Where I was stuck is I was getting JSONArray from org.json.simple and JSONObject from jettison library somehow by mistake. I will take care of posting relevant question @Engineer Dollery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution using org.JSON.simple library

```
public String ReadJsonFromFile(String fileName){
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    String firstRecord = null;
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader(fileName));
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(0);  
        firstRecord = jsonObject.toString();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        LOG.info("JSON -> Can't read from file: File Not Found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.info("JSON -> Can't read File : IO Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        LOG.info("JSON -> Can't Parse JSON in File");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return firstRecord;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The below code doesn't load the whole file as a String in memory. Although, the whole array would be in memory. For example, Gson would load about 10KB of file bytes into buffer at a time, and parse each row and add to the array. But, all 1000 objects will be on the heap in the array.

**Partial Streaming suitable for most cases**

```
public static void readDom() {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        Person[] people = gson.fromJson(reader, Person[].class);

        System.out.println("Object mode: " + people[0]);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ...
    } finally {
        ...
    }
}
```

Above code is more efficient than below:

**One shot read (Only for small files)**

```
String fileContents = FileUtils.readAsString(file);
Person[] persons = gson.fromJson(fileContents, Person[].class);
```

First approach could be okay for upto 5k-10k rows at a time. But, beyond 10k, even first approach may not be great.

This third option is the best for large data. Iterate and read one row at a time and stop whenever you want.

**True Streaming**

```
public static void readStream() {
    try {
        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

        // Read file in stream mode
        reader.beginArray();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            // Read data into object model
            Person person = gson.fromJson(reader, Person.class);
            if (person.getId() == 0 ) {
                System.out.println("Stream mode: " + person);
            }
            break;
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        ...
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Source: [Reading JSON as Stream using GSON](http://www.acuriousanimal.com/2015/10/23/reading-json-file-in-stream-mode-with-gson.html)

**Dealing with JSON parsing without matching POJO structures**

If you don't want to take the trouble of creating a matching POJO object graph structure, you could just instruct GSON to treat each row as a HashMap.

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, Object> thisRow = gson.fromJson(reader, type);
```

Comment: Hey, Teddy, nice one on the answer -- comprehensive and well formatted. But on SO we prefer no to do other people's work for them. We're here to help, not to 'do'. We're here to help with specific problems programmers are having, not to implement their algorithms for them. So, most questions should have code in them. If they don't then the correct response is to ask the OP what they've done so far and why it's not working for them, then to help them get 'their' solution right. Please read [ask]. Nice answer though.

Comment: @EngineerDollery Thanks. And I agree with you. I thought it might be useful to others as well, and maybe wanted to post before someone mentions jso*.o*g library. In any case, you are right.